# selenium POM web driver in java error

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, pageobjects

I am using the following code for POM :

```
@FindBy(xpath="[@value='Send query']") private WebElement queryButton;
```

I am getting this error

```
org.openqa.selenium.InvalidSelectorException: invalid selector: Unable to locate an element with the xpath expression [@value='Send query'] because of the following error: SyntaxError: Failed to execute 'evaluate' on 'Document': The string '[@value='Send query']' is not a valid XPath expression.
```

Comment: The acronym "POM" already has a meaning in the Java world: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apache_Maven#Project_Object_Model Please do not confuse it with Page Object Model!

Comment: If people start referring to POM as "POP" I'm probably not going to know what they're talking about.

Answer (score 3):

The error "invalid selector" is pretty explanatory: `[@value='Send query']` is not a valid XPath.

You probably meant `//*[@value='Send query']`.